# Xcode Apple Pay - PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate issues

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I am trying to implement Apple Pay into my application.  I am having an issue even establishing the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate` into my `ViewController.swift` file.

Most code samples have shown it as: `class ViewController: UITableViewController, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate`

Here is my code:

```
class ApplePayVC: UIViewController, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {
```

[image: code]

Comment: This is not a question about Xcode, so consider removing that tag and adding the [tag:swift] tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That because you must implement some of the functions of the delegate.

See in the Apple Documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html

Two functions are required :

- `paymentAuthorizationViewController(_:didAuthorizePayment:completion:)`
- `paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_:)`

You must override them, and then, the error will disappear from Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following funcs

```swift
    internal func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: ((PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)) {
        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success)
    }

    internal func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

OR

Create a new .swift file like this

```
 import Foundation

 extension UIViewController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {
    public func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: ((PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)) {
        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success)
    }

    public func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
```